# How to optimise building Docker Image using cache layer from Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: docker, azure-devops, dockerfile, azure-pipelines

Locally, if you manually build docker image multiple times with some changes, the docker daemon uses cache to speed up the docker build.

But, when I build the Docker Image from Azure DevOps pipeline, every time it's started building the image with the same dependencies/requirements which are already installed earlier. It consume a lot of time.

How do I fix this to be speed up?